# Powerpoint 2013 ribbon get twice bigger on projector view

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, lenovo-laptop

Currently I am using a Yoga 3 with Windows 8.1. I have installed Office 365 and everything seems normal however whenever I connect to projector there is a problem with Powerpoint 2013. The ribbon gets twice taller than normal view. This does not happen on other products, i.e. Word, Excel.
Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find that the Yoga comes with some software that controls the sizing of things across multiple monitors and as the Yoga changes screen orientation (landscape to portrait). Check whether disabling this or removing PowerPoint from the settings fixes the issue.